# how do I target the SVG circle in order to align it horizontally to page

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this code:

```html
<div class="gBox">
      <svg width="100%" height="300" fill="black" stroke="#9966cc" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round">
      <circle class="myCircle" transform="rotate(150 200 200)" cy="120" r="120" pathLength="170"/>
      </svg>
</div>
```

How do I target the just the "myCircle" class in CSS in order to change its properties (align it to center page...?

Comment: You target classes with a dot in css, so this would be: `.myCircle`

Comment: Are you OK with the svg being centered or do you really mean just the circle? (i.e. if the svg had other components you wouldn't want them repositioned?).

Comment: Why do you rotate the circle around the point 200 200?

Answer (score 0):

```
.myCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought and tried but it does not seem to work - the SVG does not move...I thought there is another way maybe I don't know of  related to SVG

Answer (score 0):

Here I hare two examples of placing the circle centered. In both cases the `<circle>` is centered in the SVG by setting `cx` and `cy` to 50%.

In the first example I use the viewBox attribute on `<svg>` to control the "aspect-ratio". It will always take up 100% in width, so the height will depend on the width.

In the second the circle takes up the entire space of the SVG and the size is controlled by the height attribute on `<svg>`. And then the SVG is part of a flex-box where the content is centered.

```html
<div class="gBox">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 260" fill="black" stroke="#9966cc" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round">
    <circle class="myCircle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="120" pathLength="170"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="gBox" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 260 260" height="300" fill="black" stroke="#9966cc" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round">
    <circle class="myCircle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="120" pathLength="170"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```